# LIKE оператор сравнения

Tags: php, mysql, dle

Имеется запрос, внутри которого происходит проверка соответствия.

```
SELECT * FROM dle_post WHERE xfields LIKE("%price|5000<=%")
```

Есть ли возможность через оператор `LIKE` проверить соответствие `price` меньше `5000`.
P.S Через отдельное поле нет возможности реализовать, нужно чтобы проверка осуществлялась именно через этот оператор, так как в этом поле хранится и другая информация, включая информацию о цене. Спасибо.

То есть получается есть поле `xfields`. Внутри него лежит `string` (price|5000), и мне нужно их сравнить.

Comment: сериализованные данные противоречит нормализации реляционной БД как минимум

Comment: Не делайте так - уберите лень, да перенесите это значение в отдельное поле в этой-же или другой таблице. Поле `xfields` не предназначено для поиска по его значениям.

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы делаете - это очень сильно костыльное решение, абсолютно не предназначенное для работы в живом проекте - его можно использовать разве что в одноразовом запросе для самого себя, да и в этом случае как-то сомнительно.

Всё потому, что оно очень не слабо аукнется в виде сложности поддержки этого кода, да невероятно низкой производительности.

Перенесите это значение из xfields в отдельное, независимое поле с индексом. Либо если структуру этой таблицы менять нежелательно - создайте отдельную таблицу, в которой полями будут основной ключ из dle_post и собственно цена в виде числа. После сможете спокойно искать по ней обычными, нормальными условиями.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вам поможет обрезание строки через [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index), приведение к инту через [CAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) и потом уже сравнение с нужным числом.

Например

```
SELECT * FROM dle_post WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(xfields, 'price|', -1) as UNSIGNED) <= 5000;
```

Вот для теста примеры:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX('price|5000|field|test', 'price|', -1) as UNSIGNED) <= 5000;
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX('field|test|price|5000', 'price|', -1) as UNSIGNED) <= 5000;
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX('price|5000', 'price|', -1) as UNSIGNED) <= 5000;
```

Comment: А можете еще подсказать как в этот запрос добавить OR price = 0? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @asd если `price` это колонка в таблице, то перед `;` добавить через пробел `OR price = 0`